# Delphi TTask and TThreadpool

Tags: delphi, threadpool

Is there a way to speed up the delay when TThreadpool add new tasks after it detect low cpu?

For example, I set the MaxWorkerThreads to 100 and then MinWorkerThreads to 1, then create in a loop 100 tasks:

```
for j:=0 to tthreadpool.Default.MaxWorkerThreads-1 do
begin
  task:=TTask.Run(procedure
  var
    x,i:integer;
  begin
    while ttask.CurrentTask.Status<>ttaskstatus.Canceled do
    begin
      for i:=0 to 10000 do x:=round(sin(i));
      sleep(1);
    end;
  end);
end;
```

Note that the code above is just an example with some nonsense code in it, just so the task has something to do.

CPU is below 5 all the time, and it still take TThreadPool 1 second to add a new task, which means, it take a long time until finally 100 tasks are running.

Is this because it check every second how the CPU usage is before deciding to add a new task?

Is there a way to speed this up without setting the MinWorkerThreads to 100 or is it by design and I need to use TThread?

Comment: Your "nonsense code in it, just so the task has something to do" is (or at least should be) ***atypical***. It is regularly sleeping. I.e. the thread voluntarily relinquishes CPU. (This is something best avoided as much as possible if you want high throughput of your tasks.) The point is: if you want to test thread behaviour, you should mimic the work you're likely to assign. Note: _I cannot comment on whether task/threadpool approach is appropriate for what you're trying to do because you haven't provided the relevant info._

Comment: You are not passing the thread pool as a parameter to the Run procedure. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Craig Young I want to start 100 tasks do do some web access, and parsing data, but it will never start 100 tasks, it add every second another task because it detect that the cpu usage is low. Anyway, what it does in the code is not relevant, but the question if there is a way to speed up the automatically adding of tasks when cpu is low. I guess the only way to run 100 tasks is to set the MinWorkerThreads to 100, or just using again TThread.

Comment: @Dsm As far as I know, it will use the default threadpool, so no need to add anything to the Run procedure.

Comment: @Softtouch Of course what you're doing matters! Otherwise you risk wasting your time with an X-Y Problem. (_Which it very much seems you are._) **(1)** The point of a threadpool dynamically scaling the number of threads is that it needs _time_ to _evaluate trends_. If not it could create unnecessary overhead spinning up useless threads. **(2)** Also 100 threads?? Do you have 100 cores? Do you want threads fighting each other for cores slowing ***all*** your tasks down? **(3)** Your tasks do some ***web access*** and parsing. Your bottleneck is unlikely to be CPU. (Can't parse data in transit.)

Comment: @Craig Young Yes, I thought so about (1), which is all I wanted to know. Now that this is confirmed, I will have to use tthread instead. And 100+ threads is common for the kind of software I am working on. I can run 100-200 tthreads with low cpu usage.

Answer (score 2):

For others reading this post, I've just logged a bug with quality control. It appears like the TThreadPool (at least in the latest Delphi 10.2.3) actually never goes above the MINIMUM worker count which might be why your code isn't doing what it should. There is also an issue with SetMinWorkerThreads/SetMaxWorkerThreads values on a thread pool. If max is set to say 4 and you try and set min to 8 before adjusting max to say 10, it will not set your min value. Both issues are massive gotchas here.

Adjust System.threading.pas manually as follows and add to your project...

```
function TThreadPool.ShouldGrowPool: Boolean;
begin
  Result := {(FWorkerThreadCount < FMinLimitWorkerThreadCount) and }(FIdleWorkerThreadCount < FQueuedRequestCount) and
(FWorkerThreadCount < Self.FMaxLimitWorkerThreadCount);
end;
```